# How to get "native" look for WPF widgets on windows XP?

Tags: wpf, windows-xp, themes, native, look-and-feel

I have just started playing around with WPF.

I've noticed that while some widgets automatically pick up the native look and feel (e.g, buttons, menus), some others don't (e.g., labels, panels and windows have white backgrounds).

How do I make all widgets look normal by default in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way the templates are defined in the PresentationFramework.Luna assembly. You can look at all of the default templates for all 6 Windows themes by using the ShowMeTheTemplate tool found here: http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/#ShowMeTheTemplate

-Jon